# PHP: What's the speed difference "template" vs "quote"?

Tags: php, html, performance, templates

Whats the speed difference, out of curiosity, of doing this:

```
$a = 0;
echo "<html><body>$a</body></html>";
```

versus

```
<html><body><?php echo $a; ?></body></html>
```

in a PHP file?

Comment: Negligible. Statistically irrelevant unless you do it about a million times, probably more.

Comment: Pretty much the same, both are somewhere in the 5-10ms range.

Comment: unless you're running a facebook-sized operation that's doing that sort of thing a few trillion times a day, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: @APAD1 you mean for a million iterations hopefully or your server definitely needs a replacement for its 386 CPU.

Comment: thanks for the comments, not sure why this gets downvoted. the first syntax with heredoc is much easier to read than php tags.

Comment: Neither one of your examples contains [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). And the downvotes are probably because you could've benchmarked this faster yourself than write the question.

Comment: As others have stated, the difference is probably negligible.  However, in the long run the first route is probably slower as it requires string interpolation.

Comment: Your first example isn't [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), it's simply a [double quoted string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: @Niels i'm aware of that. And my point stays the same. My question is relevant and so are the comments. Benchmarking doesn't take 1 minute. These extremely helpful answers came in 1 minute. So i call that a good question because i got it answered faster.

Comment: so you think "whats 1+1=" would be a good question?

Comment: That 1 minute of your time is also 1 minute of several other people's time

Comment: @MarkBaker Ya well i phrased it incorrectly, more like 10 minutes versus 10 seconds.

Comment: @PaulCrovella Stack overflow can be used however the eff people want to use it to get questions answered. This kind of arrogance is what makes asking questions here a pain in the butt to deal with sometimes. Stack overflow is all about helping programmers learn FASTER.

Comment: so your saying, "I can answer this question myself, but my time is more important than yours, so you do it for me"

Comment: @Dagon lets wait and see how many programmers come here from google and get their 10 minutes saved. If you are all about mass time saving the time saved by all the visitors landing from google would probably vastly outnumber the number of people answering the question.

Comment: It's amusing how you guys are spending more time arguing with him, over whether this is a valid question, than it took to answer the question. If you're so concerned about your time, what are you still doing here?

Comment: i leant to program before google existed - your selfish arrogance is rather sad.

Comment: @Dagon its not selfish arrogance its taking advantage of the awesomeness of stack overflow.

Comment: So your question got sufficiently answered with a benchmarking howto answer then?

Comment: @mario sortof. since you are here what is the technical difference between the two methods in terms of how php executes and interpolates variables in them?

Comment: As already said, there are only quite insignificant differences. One of the two approaches yields only EXT_STMT and ECHO bytecode, while the other boils down to ADD_STRING and PRINT. Use VLD and [proper profiling](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to get a picture.

Comment: @mario not a duplicate. That question uses print while this one uses plain html.

Answer (score 5):

Let's find out:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$a = 0;
$time1 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    echo "<html><body>$a</body></html>";
}
$time2 = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
?>
<html><body><?php echo $a; ?></body></html> 
<?php
}
$time3 = microtime(true);

ob_end_clean();
echo 'Just echo: ' . ($time2 - $time1) . '<br>';
echo 'Inline PHP: ' . ($time3 - $time2) . '<br>';
?>
```

Result:

```
Just echo: 0.037185907363892
Inline PHP: 0.040054082870483
```

Looks like the first method is slightly faster. But the difference is so small it's negligible and definitely not a reason to output huge blocks of HTML code by echoing strings.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, what about if you do `echo '<html><body>', $a ,'</body></html>';` (ninja edit: too lazy to put it in an eval)

Comment: theres a site that has already done it for you: http://www.phpbench.com/

Comment: Your code does not produce conclusive results in a single attempt, see https://eval.in/203304. F5 a few times to see both approaches 'win'. This is because it's fairly identical at the opcode level in PHP internally.

Comment: I immediately envisioned the Tootsie Pop commercial from the 70s when I read the opening of your answer. "Let's find out, a-wuhun, a-twohu, a-three. Three."

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes The first approach is consistently faster in my environment (Apache running on Windows) but I can definitely imagine the results being equal or reverse in other environments.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Indistinguishable from the first method (everything in one string) for me.